# Model multi tenant Hierarchical RBAC with KeyCloak -

Tags: keycloak, rbac

I am new to Keycloak and looking for help to implement the following. Are there any examples that I could refer to to achieve this ?

I have looked into Client and Resources in Keycloak, but not sure how the hierarchy would be modeled. Also how do we control permissions at different level in this hierarchy ?

**Hierarchy**

Organization -> Groups -> Apps

Organization can have multiple groups, each group can have multiple Apps

A user with write permission higher in the hierarchy will carry those permissions to resources lower in the hierarchy. For example - An admin for the org, will be admin for any application.

An user that has view permission for a Group , could be admin for an app within the Group.

What is the best way to model the permissions and the hierarchy. Also is there a way to get all the possible permissions and the corresponding entities the user is authorized for ?

Comment: Where you able to make this happen with Keycloak? I have a similar requirement and could not find an elegant solution so far. It seems odd to me that Keycloak really would not be able to create a hierarchical permission structure.

Comment: No - we spent enough time on it and took a different route

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We also now implemented this hierarchy authorization within our application and use  Keycloak for authentication only.